# How to add a QAction to specific position in a QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt

QToolBar::insertWidget allows to add a QWidget after a specific QAction.
Is there any way to add a QAction at a specific position?

Removing all actions and then re-adding them again after is my last hope !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [insertAction()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#insertAction) method, inherited from QWidget, to insert your QAction before a given QAction.